# How to let contributors to create a new revision(draft) editing their published posts

Tags: users, author, user-roles, capabilities

I'm using a custom post type to let contributors have a personal page on the site.

Any time a user registers on my site a script creates a custom type post that has the registering user as the author.

To moderate users' entries this post is published by an editor.

I would like users (contributors) to be:

- unable to add other posts of this custom type;
- able to edit the already published post they are the author of;
- and their changes must be approved by an editor before being published.

I'm using [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) to manage roles and capabilities.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Role editor or role scope you can set contributors to edit you custom post type but not publish so every change will be set as draft until approval, and to limit the creation of new posts of your custom post type you can use my plugin [**Bainternet Posts Creation Limits**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-posts-creation-limits/)

### Update

To force re approval of edits add this code

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 're_aprove', '99', 2 );
function re_aprove( $data, $postarr ) {
    //check if current user is not admin
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE' === $postarr['post_type'] ) {
        if ( 'publish' === $data['post_status'] ) {
            $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

and change `YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE` to your custom post type name.

Comment: I'm already using Role Editor and i've set up the capabilities as you suggested, but the only thing changing is that the users has an additional checkbox right above the "pubblish" button asking to "save as pending revision".

The problem is that i do not want the user to decide wether pubblish or not, they just shouldn't be able to pubblish but just save as pending revision.

Comment: If you set up correctly then they just can't publish.

Comment: i've tried but maybe there's something I do not understand.
[This is a shot of my capabilities settings](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3261727/my-role-capabilities.jpg) for the role I want to manage. As you can see hilighted, i've already set capability to edit_mycustomposttype but no pubblish_mycustomposttype. but still my users are able to pubblish edits...

Comment: OK i see what you mean, they can publish edits, that's just how wordpress works, but if you want to force re approval i updated my answer and added a function which saves the post as a draft if the user is not an admin.

Comment: 1) is it just a copy paste in functions.php?
2) do this function create a new revision or just set as pending the edited pubblished?

Comment: 1) yes, and change the custom post type name.

2) just sets the post as pending.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think the line `if ($data['post_status'] = "publish"){` should read `if ($data['post_status'] == "publish"){` - otherwise it's not testing it's assigning. Can you update your answer if I'm right?

Answer (score 4):

Mine didn't work until I added the '99' , 2); to the end of the add_filter.

Here is the reference as to why: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','re_aprove', '99', 2);
function re_aprove( $data , $postarr ){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    //check if current user is not admin
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && $postarr['post_type'] == "candy-item" ){ 
        if ($data['post_status'] = "publish"){
            $data['post_status'] = "pending";
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i've **solved** using **Revisionary** plugin,
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/
it's used to do exacly what I ask in the subject title

for more detailed control over capabilities (with revisionary already integrated) there is **Role Scoper** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/

the first one is really easy to setup and use
the second needs a lot more practice, userinterface it's a bit confusing, but it's really powerful