# Approve users posts before publish

Tags: plugins

I use of post type plugin which I've made for my website and that's allow users publish their posts in one of my two different post-types, but I need to make my post-type posts publish only when admin approve them currently they will publish directly without any checks before.

If is necessary for you to help me I will publish my plugin codes here for you too.

Update:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Classified Post-Types
Plugin URI: http://tcheck.esy.es/
Description: This plugin will add two different post types as Products & Properties into your WordPress site which allow you to convert your website into classified website and let your users to publish their ads in your website.  [for more information visit our website]
Version: 1.0
Author: Robert Nicjoo
Author URI: http://tcheck.esy.es/
License: GPLv2
*/

//Function To Show in Index.php
// Show posts of 'post', 'page' and 'movie' post types on home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product_detail', 'property_detail' ) );
  return $query;
}
//END Function To Show in Index.php

//HELP Notes
function my_contextual_help( $contextual_help, $screen_id, $screen ) { 
  if ( 'product_detail' == $screen->id ) {

    $contextual_help = '<h2>Products</h2>
    <p>Products show the details of the items that we sell on the website. You can see a list of them on this page in reverse chronological order - the latest one we added is first.</p> 
    <p>You can view/edit the details of each product by clicking on its name, or you can perform bulk actions using the dropdown menu and selecting multiple items.</p>';

  } elseif ( 'edit-product' == $screen->id ) {

    $contextual_help = '<h2>Editing products</h2>
    <p>This page allows you to view/modify product details. Please make sure to fill out the available boxes with the appropriate details (product image, price, brand) and <strong>not</strong> add these details to the product description.</p>';

  }
  return $contextual_help;
}
add_action( 'contextual_help', 'my_contextual_help', 10, 3 );
//END HELP Notes




//Start Post-Type
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_detail' );
function create_product_detail() {
    register_post_type( 'product_detail',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Products',
                'singular_name' => 'Product',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
                'new_item' => 'New Product',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Product',
                'search_items' => 'Search Products',
                'not_found' => 'No Products found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Product'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/product.png', __FILE__ ),
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
//END Post-Type


//Registering the Custom Function
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );
function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box( 'product_meta_box',
        'Product Details',
        'display_product_meta_box',
        'product_detail', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}
//END Registering the Custom Function


//Implementation of the display_product_meta_box Function
function display_product_meta_box( $product ) {
    // Retrieve current name of the Director and Movie Rating based on review ID
    $price = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'price', true ) );
    $made = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'made', true ) );
    $shipping = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'shipping', true ) );
    $quality = intval( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'quality', true ) );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Price (RP)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Made In?</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="made_in" value="<?php echo $made; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%" class="bg-primary">Shipping? (e.g. Ship,Airplane,Train, e.t.c.)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="shipping" value="<?php echo $shipping; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px">Product Quality</td>
            <td>
                <select style="width: 100px" name="product_quality">
                <?php
                // Generate all items of drop-down list
                for ( $rating = 10; $rating >= 1; $rating -- ) {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" <?php echo selected( $rating, $quality ); ?>>
                    <?php echo $rating; ?> stars <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
//End Implementation of the display_product_meta_box Function





//Registering a Save Post Function
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_movie_review_fields', 10, 2 );
function add_movie_review_fields( $product_id, $product ) {
    // Check post type for movie reviews
    if ( $product->post_type == 'product_detail' ) {
        // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
        if ( isset( $_POST['price'] ) && $_POST['price'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'price', $_POST['price'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['made_in'] ) && $_POST['made_in'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'made', $_POST['made_in'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['shipping'] ) && $_POST['shipping'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'shipping', $_POST['shipping'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['product_quality'] ) && $_POST['product_quality'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'quality', $_POST['product_quality'] );
        }
    }
}
//END Registering a Save Post Function



//Register a Function to Force the Dedicated Template
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );
function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'product_detail' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-product_detail.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-product_detail.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
//END Register a Function to Force the Dedicated Template


//Start Post-Type
add_action( 'init', 'create_property_detail' );
function create_property_detail() {
    register_post_type( 'property_detail',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Properties',
                'singular_name' => 'Property',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Property',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Property',
                'new_item' => 'New Property',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Property',
                'search_items' => 'Search Property',
                'not_found' => 'No Properties found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Properties found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Property'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/property.png', __FILE__ ),
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
//END Post-Type





//Registering the Custom Function
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin_property' );
function my_admin_property() {
    add_meta_box( 'property_meta_box',
        'property Details',
        'display_property_meta_box',
        'property_detail', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}
//END Registering the Custom Function




//Implementation of the display_property_meta_box Function
function display_property_meta_box( $product ) {
    // Retrieve current name of the Director and Movie Rating based on review ID
    $price = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'price', true ) );
    $electrisity = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'electrisity', true ) );
    $meter = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'meter', true ) );
    $room = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'room', true ) );
    $floor = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'floor', true ) );
    $yard = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'yard', true ) );
    $toilet = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'toilet', true ) );
    $bathroom = esc_html( get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'bathroom', true ) );
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Price (RP)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Electrisity (KW)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="electrisity" value="<?php echo $electrisity; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Meter M2 (e.g. 1000Meter, e.t.c.)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="meter" value="<?php echo $meter; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Room (e.g. 3 Rooms)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="room" value="<?php echo $room; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Floor (e.g. 2 Floors, e.t.c.)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="floor" value="<?php echo $floor; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Yard (e.g. include back yard)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="yard" value="<?php echo $yard; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Toilet (e.g. 2 Floors, e.t.c.)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="toilet" value="<?php echo $toilet; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Bathroom (e.g. 2, e.t.c.)</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="bathroom" value="<?php echo $bathroom; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <?php
}
//End Implementation of the display_property_meta_box Function





//Registering a Save Post Function
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_property_fields', 10, 2 );
function add_property_fields( $product_id, $product ) {
    // Check post type for movie reviews
    if ( $product->post_type == 'property_detail' ) {
        // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
        if ( isset( $_POST['price'] ) && $_POST['price'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'price', $_POST['price'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['electrisity'] ) && $_POST['electrisity'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'electrisity', $_POST['electrisity'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['meter'] ) && $_POST['meter'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'meter', $_POST['meter'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['room'] ) && $_POST['room'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'room', $_POST['room'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['floor'] ) && $_POST['floor'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'floor', $_POST['floor'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['yard'] ) && $_POST['yard'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'yard', $_POST['yard'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['bathroom'] ) && $_POST['bathroom'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'bathroom', $_POST['bathroom'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['toilet'] ) && $_POST['toilet'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'toilet', $_POST['toilet'] );
        }
    }
}
//END Registering a Save Post Function



//Register a Function to Force the Dedicated Template
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_property_template_function', 1 );
function include_property_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'property_detail' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-property_detail.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/single-property_detail.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
//END Register a Function to Force the Dedicated Template

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code is always helpful.

Comment: I found the solution [HERE][1] Thanks to all.


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17369/how-to-let-contributors-to-create-a-new-revisiondraft-editing-their-published

Answer (score 1):

// Add the content  to $post as an array

```
$post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => $_POST['cat'],  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    => $tags,
        'post_status'   => 'draft',         // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
        'post_type' => $_POST['post_type']  // Use a custom post type if you want to
    );
wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
```

Comment: which part of my code would be exactly? (where have I add this code?)